# Why is the widget with a custom painting not visible?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, python-3.7

So I'm trying to build a simple PyQt application with a custom widget. However, the painter does not paint anything. If I comment out line 44-45 (`label = QLabel('Map');box.addWidget(label)`), I can see a big colored rectangle. However, when I try to add a label above the rectangle, the rectangle doesn't show up anymore.

I think I may be using the painter wrong, but I'm not sure.

I'm new to PyQt and any comments on my coding style or logic will also be appreciated.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow,
                               QWidget,
                               QFrame,
                               QDesktopWidget,
                               QGridLayout,
                               QLabel,
                               QTextEdit,
                               QSplitter,
                               QVBoxLayout,
                               QApplication)


class Simulator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stdout = QTextEdit()
        self.stderr = QTextEdit()
        self.exec = QTextEdit()

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(self.screen)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.map = SimulatedFieldMap()

        # -- setting splitters
        splitter_r = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter_l = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter_h = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter_h.addWidget(splitter_l)
        splitter_h.addWidget(splitter_r)
        # --------------

        # -- top left --
        frame = QFrame()
        box = QVBoxLayout()
        frame.setLayout(box)
        splitter_l.addWidget(frame)
        label = QLabel('Map')
        box.addWidget(label)
        box.addWidget(self.map)
        # ------

        # -- bottom left --
        box = QVBoxLayout()
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setLayout(box)
        box.addWidget(QLabel('Exec'))
        box.addWidget(self.exec)
        splitter_l.addWidget(frame)
        # -------

        # -- top right --
        box = QVBoxLayout()
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setLayout(box)
        splitter_r.addWidget(frame)
        box.addWidget(QLabel('STDOUT'))
        box.addWidget(self.stdout)
        # -------

        # -- bottom right --
        box = QVBoxLayout()
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setLayout(box)
        splitter_r.addWidget(frame)
        box.addWidget(QLabel('STDERR'))
        box.addWidget(self.stderr)
        # -------

        self.grid.addWidget(splitter_h, 0, 0)
        splitter_h.setSizes((self.screen.width() * 0.7, self.screen.width() * 0.3))
        splitter_l.setSizes((self.screen.height() * 0.7, self.screen.height() * 0.3))
        splitter_r.setSizes((self.screen.height() * 0.7, self.screen.height() * 0.3))


class SimulatedFieldMap(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.paintMap(qp)
        qp.end()

    def paintMap(self, qp):
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 162, 200))  # lilac
        qp.setPen(QColor(200, 162, 200))
        geo = self.geometry()
        qp.drawRect(geo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    sim = Simulator()
    sim.show()
    status = app.exec_()
    exit(status)
```

[image: There is no colored rectangle on this]

I'm using Python3.7 on macOS 10.13.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a widget is painted, the internal coordinates are used, but [`geometry()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) is coordinates with respect to the parent, so you should not use it, instead you should use [`rect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Simulator(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stdout = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.stderr = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.exec = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.map = SimulatedFieldMap()

        # -- setting splitters
        splitter_r = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        splitter_l = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        splitter_h = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter_h.addWidget(splitter_l)
        splitter_h.addWidget(splitter_r)
        # --------------

        # -- top left --
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
        splitter_l.addWidget(frame)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Map')
        box.addWidget(label)
        box.addWidget(self.map)
        # ------

        # -- bottom left --
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
        box.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Exec'))
        box.addWidget(self.exec)
        splitter_l.addWidget(frame)
        # -------

        # -- top right --
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
        splitter_r.addWidget(frame)
        box.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('STDOUT'))
        box.addWidget(self.stdout)
        # -------

        # -- bottom right --
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
        splitter_r.addWidget(frame)
        box.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('STDERR'))
        box.addWidget(self.stderr)
        # -------

        screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()

        self.grid.addWidget(splitter_h, 0, 0)
        splitter_h.setSizes((screen.width() * 0.7, screen.width() * 0.3))
        splitter_l.setSizes((screen.height() * 0.7, screen.height() * 0.3))
        splitter_r.setSizes((screen.height() * 0.7, screen.height() * 0.3))


class SimulatedFieldMap(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.paintMap(qp)

    def paintMap(self, qp):
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 162, 200))  # lilac
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(200, 162, 200))
        qp.drawRect(self.rect())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    sim = Simulator()
    sim.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update:** If you want it to be placed in a certain position you should not place it in the layout but the label must be a child of the map and use `move()` to establish the position with respect to the map top-left.

```
# -- top left --
frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
box.addWidget(self.map)
splitter_l.addWidget(frame)
label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Map', self.map)
label.move(0, 100)    
# ------
```

[image]

**Update:** The problem is caused by the vertical sizePolicy of the QLabel which is `QSizePolicy::Preferred` making it expand, a simple solution is to change it to `QSizePolicy::Maximum`, so the correct height is calculated according to the font.

```
# -- top left --
frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
splitter_l.addWidget(frame)
label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Map')
sp = label.sizePolicy()
sp.setVerticalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
label.setSizePolicy(sp)
box.addWidget(label)
box.addWidget(self.map)
# ------
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How should I make the label `map` to be only one line tall instead of taking half of a screen?

Comment: To be honest, I like the solution with the size policy better than manually setting the height, because it does the job somehow automatically, meaning it will take into account the whole content (margins, etc.), not only the font size. But then again, we are allowed to upvote only once ;)

Comment: @scopchanov I understand, I just point out to the OP a more general solution

Comment: @eyllanesc, probably I have said that wrong. I mean - I like your solution better.

Comment: @scopchanov I understand, and I appreciate what you point out. :-)

Comment: @pkqxdd, I suggest you to mark __this__ answer as accepted. For an explanation why this solution is better than mine, please read my comment above.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the update. This is indeed a better solution, although the naming of `Maximum` is a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: @pkqxdd It could be contradictory if the docs are not read: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum , the sizeHint is the appropriate size, so with Maximum we are indicating that the maximum size in width or height, as the case may be, will be the sizeHint.

Answer (score 2):

## Cause

When you add a `QLabel` to the layout, its size policy is set to [`QSizePolicy.Policy(Preferred)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) by default and it will take up the whole space, leaving no space for your widget `SimulatedFieldMap`. Basically, your custom widget is there, but its height is 0, so it is not visible.

## Soultion

One solution would be to limit the height of the label by setting it to a fixed value, e.g. `14`. To do that, after `label = QLabel('Map')` add `label.setFixedHeight(14)`.

## Result

Here is the result of this solution:

[image: Window with a label, violet rectangle and input widgets.]

**Note:** For demonstration purposes I have manually moved the left vertical splitter down.

Comment: I ended up using `label.setFixedHeight(QFont().pointSize()+4)`. But I'm still curious why the `QTextEdit`s don't have the same issue?

Comment: @pkqxdd, because you put it in a vertical splitter, whose height is determined manually. Substitute the map label with a QTextEdit and you will have the same problem.